# How to code the final inner loop in my babysort function?

Tags: c++

I have a function that needs to sort values in ascending order and there are duplicates. I guess thats what i'm doing with "howMany". But i'm stuck on coding the final loop that assigns the values to counts[j].

```
void babySort(int nums[], int length){
    int counts[100]={0}; 
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        counts[nums[i]]++;
    int j=0;
    for(int index=0; index<100; index++){
        int howMany=counts[index]; 

        // need innerloop here that assigns values to counts[j]
    }
}
```

Comment: wtf is babysort? do you mean counting sort?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you describe the algorithm with words, so that we know *what* should be translated into C? As far as I can see the first loop assigns values to `count` array: this expression `counts[nums[i]]++` increments value in `count[]`, that is it assigns a value one greater than there was there before: `counts[nums[i]] = counts[nums[i]] + 1`. Isn't that what you need...?

Comment: counts the local array is counting the occurrences of each value in nums[]. then I need to overwrite nums with the values in order based on the information I have from counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just run the loop `howMany` times and overwrite the value in `nums`.

```
int j = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < howMany; ++counter)
{
    nums[j++] = index;
}
```

Now sure why do you want to re-assign values to `counts`. `counts` already stores the frequency of each number in `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

That isn’t a very efficient algorithm to begin with. Partly because it assumes that none of the values will ever be greater than 99 or less than 0, and partly because it wastes a lot of processing time if there aren’t that many numbers to sort. You’d probably be better off using an algorithm like this one:

```
void babySort(int nums[], int length) {
   int i,j;
   int Value;

   for(i = 1; i < length; i++) {
      Value = nums[i];
      for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && nums[j] > Value; j--) {
         nums[j + 1] = nums[j];
      }
      nums[j + 1] = Value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly* this is what you need:

```
void babySort(int nums[], int length){
    int counts[100]={0}; 
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        counts[nums[i]]++;

    int j=0;
    for(int index=0; index<100; index++){
        for(; counts[index]>0; counts[index]--)
            nums[j++]=index;
    }
}
```

The `for(index)` loop scans possible `index` values and when it finds one that has been encountered in the input `nums[]`, the `for(counts)` loop fills appropriate number of `nums[]` items with that value, just by counting from accumulated `count[index]` down to zero. Variable `j` counts filled items.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findMinUnique(int* originArray, int* sortedArray, int lastInsertedValue)
{
  int tempInt = 0x7fffffff;//max possible int32

  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    if(originArray[i] < tempInt && originArray > lastInsertedValue)
    {
      tempInt = originArray[i];
    }
  }
  return tempInt;
}
void babySort(int nums[], int length)
{
  int insertedValues = 0, lastInserted = -1;
  int* anotherArray = new int[length];
  //you have to allocate memory for an array, it may be of any length
  while(insertedValues < length)
  {
    int temp = findMinUnique(nums, anotherArray, lastInserted);
    for(int j = 0; j < length j++)
    {
      if(nums[j] = tempValue)
        lastInserted = anotherArray[insertedValues++] = nums[j];
    }
  }
  //if you need nums to become sorted, copy anotherArray to nums
  for(int k = 0; k < length; k++)
    nums[k] = anotherArray[k];
  delete[] anotherArray;
}
```